# Laravel Collection won't pull a value

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Collection that I am pushing a value to e.g. 'orange'. When I test for a value and attempt to pull a value, the collection remains the same.

```
$collection = collect(['red', 'green', 'blue']);

$collection->push('orange');
    
if($collection->contains('green')) {

    logger('Got green!');
        
    $collection->pull('green');
 }
```

I'm sure I am missing something trial but why is green not removed from the final collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because pull method remove item by its key not value ,so you need to get the item key ( index ) first so that you can pass it to pull or forget method to remove it .

you can do like this :-

```
$collection = collect(['red', 'green', 'blue']);

$collection->push('orange');
    
if($collection->contains('green')) {

    logger('Got green!');
          $index = $collection->search('green');

    $collection->pull($index);
    // $collection->forget($index);

 }
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I wrongly assumed that push and pull would operate as opposites, meaning if I could do something with one, the other would 'reverse' that operation.

Comment: you can use offsetUnset() method which is implemented in forget() method
furthermore offsetUnset accept one key and return void, forget() accept many keys or one and return collection after removal, pull return the item removed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually simple non-associative array in php still associative, but its **keys** are **indexes** and you can imagine your array as

```
[0 => 'red', 1 => 'green', 2 => 'blue', 3 => 'orange']
```

Pull method **pulls** the item from array **by its key**. So if you expect to orange item being pulled you should call the method with that item's index:

```
$collection>pull(3);
```

Comment: You may ask yourself: 'what the heck?! why are you talking about arrays?' But laravel collection is a wrapper (extremely cool btw. I badly miss it in Symfony) of php arrays :)

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the insight. I assumed push and pull would always work as opposites.

Comment: Im not sure but the opposite method of push in terms of algorithms and data structures is pop :) these methods came from stack (LIFO) data structure specs